# How do I get Selenium Server to launch Chrome on 64bit Windows under Jenkins with Selenium Grid?

Tags: selenium, windows, jenkins

I am migrating a Selenium server environment from Windows 2008 server 32bit to Windows 2008 server 64bit. Whenever I try to run a job with Google Chrome, I get the following error message:

```
Error Message

Could not start Selenium session: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: 
Error forwarding the new session The server returned an error : 
Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.os.WindowsRegistryException:  
Problem while managing the registry, OS Version '6.1', regVersion1 = falseBuild 
info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:08:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_11'Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: 

org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Error forwarding the new session The server returned an error : Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.os.WindowsRegistryException: Problem while managing the registry, OS Version '6.1', regVersion1 = falseBuild info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:08:56'System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_11'Driver info: driver.version: unknown
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:109)   
 at edu.umich.oud.dart.bad_link_tests.TestChromeQa.setUp(TestChromeQa.java:9) 
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Error forwarding the new session The server returned an error : Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.os.WindowsRegistryException: Problem while managing the registry, OS Version '6.1', regVersion1 = falseBuild info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:08:56'System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_11'Driver info: driver.version: unknown  
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:112)     
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getCommandResponseAsString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:183)    
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.executeCommandOnServlet(HttpCommandProcessor.java:118)   
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:101)     at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:275)  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.start(HttpCommandProcessor.java:237)  
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:100)
```

I used the alternate install of Chrome that installs in `Program Files (x86)` and I've included both the Selenium Driver directory and directory with `chrome.exe` in the PATH environment variable.

The environment is as follows:

- Windows 2008 Server x64
- Java JDK 7u11
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.34
- Jenkins 1.499
- Selenium plugin for jenkins
- Selenium Grid (as part of the selenium plugin)
- Selenium server 2.25 (part of selenium plugin)
- Chrome 24
- ChromeDriver 26 (also tried the last release)
- Firefox 10 ESR

Comment: Lucas, please use code formatting that preserves white spaces. It is hard to read now. You may prefix it with `<!-- language: lang-none -->` to avoid syntax highlighting.

Comment: The output from jenkins isn't that great either.  I've tried to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Narrowed the problem down to a windows account issue. I can launch it from tomcat using an administrator account, but not the user it's running as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Selenium IRC channel](http://seleniumhq.org/support/) provided a hint. The browser was starting to launch, but Selenium never got a reply.  After some fiddling, I was able to remote desktop into the account selenium + tomcat ran as and manually launched a grid job.  Chrome was trying to setup a second desktop shortcut and do some initial first launch housecleaning. I also had to relax the permissions on `C:\program files (x86)\google\chrome\application` a bit.

After this, Chrome will launch on the grid as expected.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know Selenium has IRC channel :-)

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted so if other people have the same issue they can easily see that this was the solution.